# how to solve the permission denied Anaconda

Tags: python, windows-7, anaconda

I am trying to install a package for python on windows7. 
I use **pip install**

I get the following error

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215
, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", lin
e 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784
, in install
    **kwargs
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line
 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line
 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in m
ove_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 323, in c
lobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\Lib\\site-pa
ckages\\numexpr\\interpreter.pyd'
```

I searched and I found that some people say that I must update the conda or anaconda.

I did this

Then I did this, but it denied .

```
conda update conda


C:\Users\Administrator>conda update conda
Fetching package metadata ...

CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-
64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io', por
t=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caus
ed by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSCon
nection object at 0x0000000005A257F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Er
rno 10051] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network',))",),)
```

what if I dont want to have Anaconda, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you conda install packages at all?

Comment: @ally-e how can I check that?